# How do I search for hashTag in SearchController?

Tags: swift, search, rx-swift, hashtag

I'm going to search for hashtags. The current code is now complete with the creation of a search bar. I am using RxSwift and Mvvm pattern. Here's the code I've been working on so far.How should I search for hashtags?

```
    func setUI() {
        self.searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x:300, y:0, width:300, height:20))

        searchBtn.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
            self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
            self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:300, height:20)

            }
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

    }
```

This is ViewController.

```
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    struct input {
        let loadData: Signal<Void>

    }

    struct output {
        let result: Signal<String>
        let loadApplyList: PublishRelay<friends>
    }

    func transform(_ input: input) -> output {
        let api = SearchAPI()
        let result = PublishSubject<String>()
        let loadApplyList = PublishRelay<friends>()

        input.loadData.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            api.getFriend().subscribe(onNext: { (response, statuscode) in
                switch statuscode {
                case .ok:
                    if let response = response {
                        loadApplyList.accept(response)
                    }
                default:
                    print("default")
                }
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        return output(result: result.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ""), loadApplyList: loadApplyList)
    }
}
```

And this is viewModel

Comment: does your API takes hashtag as search string? How is it anyway different from passing a plain text or hashtag? this should be a contract between client and your API team to tell them that this is a hashtag, this is a plain text etc etc and based on that your backend should send results, not sure how this question is relevant here :|

Comment: Does your API have a `searchHashtag` method?